# Angular 4 doesn't send Cookies with "withCredentials: true"

Tags: angular

I have following Code with an Post Request.

```
submitOffer(val: NewOfferForm) {
        const body = JSON.stringify({data: val, TOKEN: this.currentUser.token});
        return this.http.post(this.pathRoute.path + 'NEW_OFFER', body, { withCredentials: true })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                const Response = response.json();
                if (Response) {
                    return Response;
                } else {
                    return response.json().ERROR;
                }
            });
    }
```

I've set Cookies in Angular and want to send them with the request, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which cookie you want to send ?

Comment: A cookie named 'user'